# Determine active rows from multiple tables and place in a Variable Table

Tags: sql, sql-server, variables

I have to determine how many rows are active from each Table. Then return the answers in one query AND put the results in a Table Variable.

```
a. Path     
b. Course   
c. Section 
d. Event
```

I was able to determine the active rows with the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM [dbo].[ADF_Path]
WHERE PathActive is NULL

SELECT * FROM [dbo].[ADF_Course]
WHERE CourseActive = '1'OR 
CourseActive = 'y'

SELECT * FROM [dbo].[ADF_Event]
WHERE EventActive = 'y'
```

Is it POSSIBLE to join these tables in order to arrive at the same conclusion
OR
How do I determine the active rows in 1 query?
Placing the query in a Variable Table is not a problem. I just need to know 
how to formulate the query. (See Tables below)
Thank You

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

do you want something like?:

```
SELECT count(*) as cnt FROM [dbo].[ADF_Path] WHERE PathActive is NULL
union all
SELECT count(*) FROM [dbo].[ADF_Course] WHERE CourseActive = '1' OR CourseActive = 'y'
union all
SELECT count(*) FROM [dbo].[ADF_Event] WHERE EventActive = 'y'
```

you can also add column to distinguish between different counts, or summarize them like:

```
select sum(cnt) from ( <union query from above> ) as t
```

Comment: Thanks. I have added the tables for clarity

Comment: @Eda how events table is connected with other tables?

Comment: Either the EventID or DocumentID corresponds to IDs on other tables

Comment: @Eda event id 1001 is it path or course or section?

Comment: @Eda why do you think so?

Comment: That was from the Table Diagram... unless I have it mixed up.

Comment: Thank you Lashane. It looks like UNION ALL will do the job. I'll run it and place it in a Variable Table